# Jetty SSL server

Tags: security, ssl, jetty

Following is my code for the secure ssl server. I have created a keystore "server" and it has the key pair generated with passwords.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server();

    HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration();
    https_config.setSecureScheme("https");
    https_config.setSecurePort(8443);
    https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
    https_config.setSendServerVersion(true);

    File keystoreFile = new File("server");
    System.out.print(keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    if (keystoreFile.exists())
    {
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath(keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("secret");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("secret");
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("secret");
        sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
            "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");
    }
    ServerConnector https =
            new ServerConnector(server,
                    new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
                    new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
    https.setPort(8443);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { https});
    ServletContextHandler scHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server,"/");
    scHandler.addServlet(Testpage1.class, "/test");
    server.setHandler(scHandler);
    server.start();
}

}
```

when I tried to connect to using the https://localhost:8443/ or https://localhost:8443/test it gives me "web page not available error" and with curl it gives me "curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:8443" 
Could some one guide me to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post the question after a full day of debugging and trials and but with a little suggestion from a friend I manage to solve the issue by updating the keystore. So the issue I was having was due to the keys I have generated int he key store. It seems you need to use RSA algorithm not the EC algorithm.

Comment: Hi @Tharanga, could you tell if you use keytool and how you use it to change to RSA? thanks in advance.

Comment: No  I used a key store explorer instead.